# Doorkeeper token revoke callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, doorkeeper

I'd like to invoke some code that requires the request object and the user when a token is revoked. It appears that Doorkeeper does not have the configuration to hook into the token revocation process. Perhaps, there's a better way to achieve this.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out.  The code below will remove all the tokens for a particular resource owner.

```rb
Doorkeeper::AccessToken.where(resource_owner_id: "some-id").delete_all
```